# Story of a spaceship swallowed by lush vegetation

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

About 20 years ago I've read a short story about a scientific expedition that landed on seemingly harmless planet with lush vegetation. Their ship landed on a grassy plain then the crew set to exploring.

They died one by one but I don't remember the circumstances (and it's my main point of interest now). When there was no one left, the ship's systems tried to send a distress signal home but before it could align its antenna, it turned out that they landed not upon the ground but on top of gigantic grass that split itself and the ship tumbled down, swallowed by dense vegetation.

I'd be grateful if anyone could point me to the story, remembers why members of the expedition died and/or could find suitable illustration of that giant grass. Actually I tried to find such picture but to no avail - perhaps I was using wrong keywords.